# CSS Animation of pseudo-elements is not working in FF

Tags: javascript, css, loops, animation

I tested this css loop in Chrome and Safari - works good. But the animation is not working in Firefox and IE.

Where is the problem? I defined the -moz- prefix already.
Or should I stop using css transitions for pseudo-elements?

```
/* fullscreen div */
section_2.cd-single-project.is-loaded.is-full-width:after {
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;

/* name */
-webkit-animation-name: fading; 
-moz-animation-name: fading;
-ms-animation-name: fading;
-o-animation-name: fading;
animation-name: fading;

/* count */
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;

/* duration */
-webkit-animation-duration: 12s;
-moz-animation-duration: 12s;
-ms-animation-duration: 12s;
-o-animation-duration: 12s;
animation-duration: 12s;   
}

/* fade safari */
@-webkit-keyframes fading {
0%   { background-image:url("1.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;background-size: cover; }
25% { background-image:url("2.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;background-size: cover; }
50%   { background-image:url("3.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;background-size: cover; }
}

/* fade firefox */
@-moz-keyframes fading {
0%   { background-image:url("1.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;background-size: cover; }
25% { background-image:url("2.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;background-size: cover; }
50%   { background-image:url("3.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;background-size: cover; }
}

/* fade opera */
@-o-keyframes fading {
0%   { background-image:url("1.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;background-size: cover; }
25% { background-image:url("2.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;background-size: cover; }
50%   { background-image:url("3.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;background-size: cover; }
}

/* fade general */
@keyframes fading {
0%   { background-image:url("1.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;background-size: cover; }
25% { background-image:url("2.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;background-size: cover; }
50%   { background-image:url("3.jpg"); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;background-size: cover; }
}
```

Comment: can you share your HTML markup too please

Comment: i have issue with animation in ie too ...

Comment: i tried to create a fiddle but I think that's a even better way: [link](http://www.fritz-marketing.de/showcase/der_loewe/)

Comment: i used a pretty good example from codyhouse and added a fading background when you open the section. just no. 2 is currently animated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add "animation-fill-mode: both" to see something.
What is hapenning, I think, is that maybe the animation is already over or isn't triggered.

Comment: you mean 

#section_2.cd-single-project.is-loaded.is-full-width:after 
{
animation-fill-mode: both;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
...
}

Comment: sorry, no result at all

Answer (score 0):

`section_2` is not a valid selector unless custom element `<section_2></section_2>` is within `html` ?

Is `section_2` a `class` of an element , missing `.` `.section_2` ?, or an `id` of an element missing `#` `#section_2` ?

Comment: oh sorry it's a id "#section_2"

Comment: @ThomasKu _"it's a id "#section_2""_ Does adjusting selector return expected results ?

Comment: it was just a typo in my question here. the sector is valid an works fine. the animation is triggering in chrome + safari.

Comment: @ThomasKu Try adding `position` , `display` properties to `:after` pseudo element

Comment: i added `position`  +  `display` no effects in FF. here's the link to the project. maybe this will help you to understand it better  [link](http://www.fritz-marketing.de/showcase/der_loewe/)

Comment: @ThomasKu Not certain what expected result is ? `'img/img-2-small.jpg';` at `.projects-container .cd-single-project:nth-of-type(2)::before {
content: 'img/img-2-small.jpg';
}` should display content as string ? Are media queries preventing animations to be called ? Trying ff, chrome, safari at same display ?